# Special sudoku matrix. is it possible to solve this?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

So there is a matrix $7\times5$

The matrix elements can only be one of seven values, these are $1,-1,2,-2,3,4,5$.

I want to assign one of those values to each element in the matrix such that every column has all the values in it but every line does **not** contain neither duplicates of values **nor both a number and its negative**

So a line can contain either value $1$ or $-1$ but not both. And the same for $2$ and $-2$.

So the question is: **Is it possible to assembled this matrix? If yes, then what is its shape, or how can I put it together?**

Comment: Try placing the $3,4,5$s first so that each row has no more than two gaps for $\pm1$ and $\pm2$.  You should see why this is impossible fairly quickly

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  $5\times 7$ matrices have $7$ columns each with $5$ elements.  Did you mean that or did you mean to have $5$ columns each with $7$ elements?  And what does "every line" refer to?  Is "line" meant to be "row"?

Comment: @RobPratt I have corrected the mistake. It's indeed a 7 x 5 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is impossible.  You cannot even place $1$ and $-1$.  If each column contains both $1$ and $-1$, that requires $10$ of these values.  But you have only $7$ rows, so by the pigeonhole principle some row must contain more than one entry with absolute value $1$.